# Matlab: All combination of a matrix rows

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 15*2 matrix and want to have all possible combinations including 3 rows from 15 rows..`nchoosek(15,3)=455` it means `455subsets`(3*2matrix) is possible.
Can't I have the subsets?

Answer (score 0):

```
n=3
M=reshape(x(nchoosek(1:size(x,1),n),:),[],n,size(x,2))
```

To get each individual combination, use:

```
squeeze(M(k,:,:))
```

where k is the index.

Comment: I didn't get the desired result !

Comment: @Elahek: Please explain where this results differs from what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, it was correct.I get the exact result  for(i=1:nchoosek(15,3))
t=squeeze(M(i,:,:));
end